# Identify whether a portable executable is an ssh client application

Tags: c++, ssh

As the title depicts, I need to develop a C++ program that identifies whether a `.exe` file is an ssh client application. I have done some research, but things aren't clear in my head, which of these solutions might apply to this problem:

> Do I have parse the .exe referring to the portable executable file format or just read through the binary and check for a specific "client ssh application thing".

How do ssh client applications differ from others, what is their distinct characteristic that will help me distinguish or point to them. A simple, naive solution to display raw binary would be represented by the code below. Now someone said to search for the word "ssh" on this data (which means I could apply a regex pattern on the string and find whatever comes next to ssh). Are there any other ways though to come up with a solution to this?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream fs;

    fs.open(argv[0], std::ios::binary);
    if (fs.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    fs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::size_t index = fs.tellg();

    char* buff = new char[index];
    fs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    fs.read(buff, index);
    fs.close();

    std::string s;
    s.assign(buff, index);
    delete[] buff;

    std::cout << s;

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Doubt you can do this in any reliable way for all possible executables. Why do you need to do this? What's the underlying goal?

Comment: If your goal is to find a given string in a binary file and you're having problems getting your code to work, then that's on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: 99% of the problem would be solved by "is it called putty.exe or ssh.exe?". The remaining 1% may include encrypted executables where you have no chance to tell what they do without running them (and with some debugger&VM detecting techniques possibly not even then).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) it is **impossible** to look at a program and automatically figure out whether the program does a certain thing. That's why virus scanners are so complicated and not always accurate.

You might look for the string "ssh", but what if someone doesn't want you to know their program is an SSH client program, so it stores the string "tti!dmjfou" and then subtracts 1 from all the ASCII codes when you run it?